# Android studio emulator nor Genymotion nor USB real device working

Tags: android, emulation

Its been a week I have been stuck with this emulators since I have downloaded it.
I have gone through almost all the threads available in this forum or out. 
I have followed the exact tutorials provided or suggested but none has helped me. 
I even created new virtual devices and changed the heap size, RAM (514 MB) size for the AVD available in android studio the screen is just stuck on the first screen. Even if I left it for half day it didn't work.

Then I found the next solution through this forum to download Genymotion, It also didn't work it doesn't creates the folders in my program files, so downloaded it directly through its website now it doesn't supports the any version of virtual box.

Now the other solution which I found says we can use the real device to test our programs through USB.I followed the procedure now it doesn't suppoert the device drivers, I installed them too.

and finally this shitty thing doesn't work. 
I'm using windows 7 , android studio 2.2.3
Please help me I'm a beginner trying to learn. Please help me sorry for long question.

Regards,
Rachita

Comment: I tried most of solutions, but with no or little success.. except one - VMware + Android x86 4.4.r4 image.. this combination runs on my LINUX machine very nicely.. maybe give it a try on your windoze..

Comment: I know the feeling. Testing on USB can be tricky sometimes because of phone drivers. What I can say is that I use Nox, Memu and Droid4x and all three work very well as emulators. All I have to do is run the emulator AFTER clicking the run button. If the emulator is already running, it won't be seen.

Comment: @n0rph3u5 I din't get what you are trying to suggest.

Comment: @rachita what is your CPU Type?If its 32 Bit I am sorry to say genymotion is now available only for 64 bit CPU...it won't work with  your system configuration ...for usb debugging i would like to know your device details??

Comment: @Beppi's I'll try with the suggested emulator by you. Hope it works.

Comment: @PN10 my device is 64 bit, I'm using lenovo R400 series with windows 7 64 bit OS, with Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8400 @ 2.26ghz , with 2GB RAM.

Comment: @Rachita ..ok, so for testing my android apps on my PC (64bitAMD + Linux Mint) I am using  combination of `VMware Workstation Player 12.5` (which exists for windows too) + `Android-x86 4.4-r4` image downloaded from `osboxes.org`..

Comment: @n0rph3u5 thankyou for your time, I'll try and let you know if it worked for me.

Comment: @Rachita if that the case i think there should be no issue with system configuration ...I would like to know few more details regarding real device (mobile) ,about the errors coming with genymotion , real device, and avd .....also it would be better if you provide screen shot of your error for better clearity ...please edit your question ....with all details..

Comment: I can't understand why someone downvoted this question, it's a real problem still today 2024

Answer (score 1):

**Testing on emulator**

I use Memu, Nox and Droid4X with success. There should be no real issue. When you want to test an app from Android Studio, click the run button (*shift-F10*) and when it opens the emulators window run the emulator. In that way it will be seen and listed in the window as available device. It won't be seen if the emulator is already running *before* the emulators list is open for the first time, for some reason I never understood. Probably this problem is fixable using adb directly.

**Testing on USB**

Attach the phone via USB and accept the asked authorizations on the phone. You have to have set the phone with the option *USB Debug* to do so. Generally it works, but it might need phone drivers on the PC.

**Testing on WiFi**

After attaching the phone via USB, if both PC and phone are connected on WiFi you can use it to debug. To do this you have to use adb directly, in this way:

```
cd android\android-sdk\platform-tools
adb kill-server
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect <phone ip address>
adb devices -l
```

Then you can detach the USB and you will be able to debug on Wifi.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was the wifi testing

Answer (score 0):

when your connect your phone to your computer can you see the device ,if you cant see it ,that may means your computer didnt have the properly driver for your phone ,if you can see you phone on the computer but android studio cant connect it ,that may be wrong with you adb.exe ,resart it may be working ,hope it work for you.

Comment: thanks Larrysea for a quick response, But unfortunately I have done that and my device is dedected in the sytsem when I run the configuration is it ask me to update my drivers. I have done that also have restarted the studio many times, even ended the abd.exe from the task manager, but still no luck.

Comment: when you kill adb.exe and also need to start it.look the message in android monitor that may show your what the real problem .

Comment: I restarted it to. It always gives me error asking me to reduce the RAM size which I have already done. In studio as well as hard coded it in the driver file. but it still keeps poping the same error and its stuck on the loding screen itself. Thankyou alot for your time.